# Rep bug on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51

I used to have 91 rep on Area 51, 51 start rep + 40. This is what's shown in the `/reputations` page, and the items in my profile also add up to 40. But Area 51 now shows I have only 27 rep (which means I can't even comment).

Comment: Have you tried a recalc?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Felix Dombek: via `http://sitename.com/reputation` - http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: @jweyrich: It shows my rep at 91, but a visit on the site still shows 27. The reputation in my profile's tab adds up to exactly 40.

Comment: Have you tried emailing team@stackexchange.com and request a recalc?

Comment: no, I thought this was faster and there was an onsite way to do that. But thanks! I'll do it.

Comment: They still haven't answered and my reputation has dropped to 1. /reputation still shows it as 63 but someone has obviously found it funny to give me a "not a good example" on virtually all my questions. I don't want to be too fast with accusations but I think I have grounds to believe it is the guys from the "Fisica" proposal, who have already had the impertinence of calling me "xenophobic", which is why I wanted to comment there in the first place .. just when this bug occurred!!! This is an outrage! Can someone please help me?!!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your account was the target of malicious down-voting. A single user used 3 accounts to issue 63 "not a good example" votes against you over a 2-day span. The unusual votes were automatically detected and deleted, so your reputation has returned to normal. The two sock puppet accounts were merged into the original one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But isn't it still strange that http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputations showed such a grossly different number than my profile? I mean, the calculation in my profile was correct, but the total number as used everywhere on the site wasn't.

Comment: @Felix that *might* be down to caching I think. Or has that been ruled out?

Comment: That makes sense ... not sure how I could rule it out -- I understood the comment by benny above in a way that the /reputations page kind of circumvents the cache and does a recalc to immediate effect, but as I read it now again, it doesn't say that this is the case at all.

Comment: @Felix The discrepancy was caused by a bug (which we're fixing now). The bug was that if multiple accounts maliciously targeted a single account in one day, the rep recalc was only performed after deleting votes cast by the first account, instead of after *all* the malicious votes were deleted. In your case, since your account endured a second day of malicious down-voting (by just one user this time), another rep recalc was performed, so your reputation happened to correct itself on its own.

Comment: @Emmett: while you're fixing bugs, I have another one for you: The check mark under my original answer does not disapper (I simply clicked the checkmark of your post without removing my checkmark first) and now I see both as "accepted". Clicking on the checkmark of my answer, however, reveals a "Found no accepted answers to undo" message, while trying to delete my answer results in a "You cannot delete this accepted answer" message.

Comment: @Felix Yup I noticed that too. To facilitate better indexing for changes to search that we're rolling out soon, we changed the way that accepted answers are saved. Clearly this caused some bugs.. this'll be fixed shortly.