# What to do about unjustified "not a good example" votes on Area51?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, down-votes, users

Someone marked virtually all my recent questions for new proposals on Area51 as "Not a good example" without any comment -- even some which had already been voted as "On-topic" or "Off-topic". Similar questions by other people were not marked as such.

As I recently had a discussion about a proposal, [Fisica](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27913/fisica), where those in favour of the proposal ended up being quite offensive, I think I have grounds to believe that this was someone's "retaliation" towards me with no factual reasons for the bad votes.

Right now, I can't do anything on Area51 because of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76019/rep-bug-on-area51) (which also made me wonder how to attract the attention of admins, because I've even written mails to area51@SE and team@SE) but generally, I'd like to know if there is any policy regarding such events.

I guess the first thing is to comment on the downvoted questions asking for the downvoter's reason, but as s/he left no comment there in the first place, the chance that they are interested in a discussion seems marginal. Also, of course, I cannot comment right now, because of aforementioned bug. Unjustified downvotes are also bad for the proposals in question, I believe, and of course bad for my rep, which is why I don't just want to let it rest right now.

I'm extremely grateful for any answers and help or ideas on this.

---

Gosh, it happened AGAIN! Thanks to Pekka, I got enough rep to make a statement in the Fisica discussion -- *promptly* another downvote on something which is clearly not a bad example, and a rep loss which prevents me from posting comments again. Do I have any chance of finding out who did it?! Anonymity yes please, but I'd at least like to know if there is exactly one person responsible ... and if so, have this monkey banned, for they treat SE sites like 4chan or something. Grrr!

---

Problem solved by flagging this -- thank you, kind moderator.

Comment: good question, I saw this happening as well (to my questions).

Comment: This question in its exact form isn't relevant anymore because the old "good example" voting system on Area 51 was removed. However, reading into it, a similar situation exists for the current voting system, and it's probably worth directing users experiencing a similar issue to [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may indeed be retaliatory voting. I don't know whether the [serial downvote detection mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim) applies to Area 51 as well - check back in 24 hours.

I wouldn't worry too much about it either way, seeing as this doesn't threaten your proposal in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean the proposal to close Fisica? My real problem is, I just lost all my rep within 14 hours and can't get new rep because I can't do anything which gives me rep! Also, I'd like to re-enter the discussion on Fisica. To just not reply to someone's comment towards me seems a very bad thing.

Comment: @Felix I see. I'll walk through your example questions and upvote a few I think are on-topic. It's not *entirely* supposed to work that way but it shouldn't be a problem, I'll see to it that I vote only on what I can understand :)

Comment: thank you very much =) I hope sooner or later an admin is going to give me back my 50 start rep and make the /reputations page and my profile show the same values again.

Comment: FYI: the serial downvote mechanism does apply to Area51 as stated at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76019/rep-bug-on-area51/76564#76564

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about the "Homework" proposal. It looks like other users also had some "not a good question" votes, so I don't think there is good evidence that someone was going after you.  Looks like that proposal has been closed as being poorly defined anyway, so even more reason to believe the votes were not targeted just at you.

If it bugs you leave a comment, but I would not worry about it.

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily: The other downvotes were there before, as far as I recall, and also Music and Metal Music are affected. (Also, even for homework, it's completely strange that all of the sudden all my 5 questions get exactly 1 negative point -- exactly at the same time as those on Music and Metal Music.) But ok, Area51 now shows me 51 rep again, and I can comment everywhere. That's half the issue. The other half is obviously that my /reputations page shows me 113 rep, so I hope someone with database access is going to look what's going on there.