# Sock puppets on area 51

Tags: support, area-51, sock-puppets

These [two](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/31222/bobby) [users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/31225/fischer) appear to be a sock puppet combo (both following the same proposal). Just not sure how to report this type of activity as there is no flag link from a user profile page. Is there a way to alert mods on this type of activity without having to use the contact-us link at the bottom of the page?

Comment: The "Fisica" proposal seems to create [quite a lot of trouble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76090/what-to-do-about-unjustified-not-a-good-example-votes-on-area51) today.

Comment: @Pekka - That question is what took me to the proposal and I noticed the puppets on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually these things get reported to `team@stackoverflow.com`. Unfortunately this isn't exactly well known and advertised.

However since your already here a mod might go ahead and take care of it

Comment: Is there not a team@area51.com or similar address. The reason I'm asking here is to also provide a future reference for people spotting sock puppetry of the bad kind on Area 51.

Comment: @xiao Probably not, this email is for pretty much the entire network.

Comment: @xiao AFAIK, all reports can go into the `team@stackoverflow.com`  bucket.

Comment: @Pekka @TheLQ - Thanks both. I'll send an email off now. Cheers.