# Answer accepted twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76019/rep-bug-on-area51/76564#76564) seems to have two accepted answers - @Felix's was accepted on January 1, 2001.

Is this a known bug? It doesn't seem a duplicate of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/answer-accepted-twice), which has its roots in a race condition.

Comment: I was originally going to link [some earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47964/bug-awarded-double-rep-for-accepted-answer) [reports like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/answer-accepted-twice), but this is something completely different. For the record, that timestamp is the same as what happens when a deleted user has acceptance, in case that points anything out. The [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/76019/timeline) shows the answer as unaccepted, so something must've glitched to keep it still labeled as such.

Comment: Another case popped up just a few hours before you asked this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53096/function-to-convert-an-answer-to-a-new-question/76514#76514

Comment: @Pop good catch. Must be related to some recent change

Comment: Roots in a race condition? The time difference is 22 seconds, I wouldn't expect the SO hardware to be that slow.

Comment: @BalusC ah, it was just Pollyanna's suspicion, not official word. I misread.

Comment: @Jeff `status-completed`, but how?

Comment: @will sql is a hell of a drug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen this on SO (lost the link immediately).  Could be an issue with a merge between questions that had answers, or an answer being accepted after a merge but before the user refreshed the merged question.  Or it could be aliens.

Comment: Aliens with... __cosmic rays__?!

Answer (score 0):

I could have sworn that this was a dupe, but I can't find one. If I recall correctly, January 1, 2001 is a special date for Stack Exchange. (To be more specific, it's 01/01/01 at 0000 hours.) It shows up sometimes in migrations and other situations where, say, an action on a post predates the post's creation date.