# Question with three accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

How comes this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-for) has three accepted answers ([Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-for/1918210#1918210), [tdammers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-for/3511031#3511031), [BalusC's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918196/why-doesnt-changing-the-pre-to-the-post-increment-at-the-iteration-part-of-a-for/2623734#2623734))?

Bug, feature or is Firefox just cheating me (happening quite often lately)?

**Edit** (considering comments): more likely a bug according the time stamps on the second two check-marks

**Edit 2**: bug, probably caused by 2 other question being merged to that question (as noted by Shog9, see below).

Comment: This looks like an extension of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76574/answer-accepted-twice). That said, the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1918196/timeline) of that question has some really wonky stats in terms of acceptance.

Comment: Bug.  If you look at the time stamps on the second two checkmarks, they are very wrong.

Comment: I want to accept an answer too!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be possible. Given the accept times, I'm guessing Paul's is the real accepted answer.

Comment: @Grace - yes, seams so, but the question referenced by [that bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76574/answer-accepted-twice) (now) only has one answer at all.

Comment: Interesting, Carlos. The titular example, the other answer was deleted. Pop's example in the comments doesn't have any deleted answers but the acceptance was cleared. Strange, strange.

Comment: FWIW, [two other questions were merged](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1918196/revisions) into that one... Normally, this *doesn't* result in multiple accepted answers, but in this case it appears that two folks got lucky!

Comment: I have a feeling though that this (the check marks showing) is a recent phenomenon. My bet is it's not more than a week or two old.

Comment: @Pekka - second that... I never noted it before. @Shog9 - thanks, seams like that is the *source*

Comment: @Pekka, @Shog9 - you're both right, it is recent and it is with merges, see my answer below, the fix has already been deployed to correct existing and prevent it in future merges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was a change I put in that stored Accepted answer directly on the answer...as a result of that and not considering question **question merges**, answers that were migrated (75 on SO) "carried over" the check with the merge.

A fix this this has been deployed, fixing the data and correcting the display to what it was previously.

Comment: Well done. Most new employees wait at least a month before breaking things, but you're ahead of the game already!

Comment: Any chance you broke the OR queries about an hour ago?

Comment: @Hans - not that I'm aware of, are you having issues?

Comment: It's doggone goofy, I'll try to document it when I see some kind of pattern.