# Checkmark Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

I found a bug:

[image]

Look at the question: [Can the number of cookies set on localhost create problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487389/can-the-number-of-cookies-set-on-localhost-create-problems)

Two answers are clearly marked as correct. I hit refresh and it stays. On both of the member's profiles, the question shows up as marked correct.

Is this a bug, or just a "new feature"? Thanks for checking it out for me!

I tested myself on a question, it still flipped which one was marked for me.

Comment: [Timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6487389/timeline) also shows that both questions have been marked individually as accepted.  9 seconds apart, maybe a race condition somewhere?

Comment: @Jeff Looks like it.

Comment: I refuse to upvote this until it's retitled "Checkmark Overflow"

Comment: Probably a merge condition

Comment: The [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/6487389) shows [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487389/can-the-number-of-cookies-set-on-localhost-create-problems/6487415#6487415) one to be the correct accepted answer.

Comment: I've merged two questions that both had accepted answers before, and I've never seen this.  The accepted answer on the target stays accepted.  (Of course, this doesn't discount recent code changes around merging.)

Comment: @George, if the API can tell which answers are correct, then why doesn't it automatically tick the correct answer as soon as it is posted? Or even better, why doesn't it just auto-answer with the correct answer? ... ;)

Comment: The checkmarks are both gone now.

Comment: @Michael: Done :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Answer accepted twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/answer-accepted-twice); see also the similarly named [Answer accepted twice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76574/answer-accepted-twice) and [Question with three accepted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76952/question-with-three-accepted-answers)

Comment: Please close as a dupe, not too localized. (It's 2/2 now)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bug, it happens **VERY** rarely.

I already have a daily job that clears this mess up and alerts us when it happens.

I do not particularly want to add a crazy amount of locking and checking just to combat the very rare cases.

Comment: @YOU 404? What was it?

Comment: @YOU yes ... sorry we did not want to advertise that ... it was benign bug ... but still

Comment: ah ok, got it.

Comment: Done it "clear it up" by [deleting both](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96502/checkmark-overflow#comment-242732)? Because that seems kind of bad